# How to transfer text from a text box using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I simply want to set a cell equal to the text inside a text box after pressing a command button using vba, is this possible? I don't know how to find the textbox (or inserted shape) name to call in VBA.
Thanks in advance.

The image above shows my general layout. The Three boxes in the Frame Interface tab under General notes, Abbreviation, and project notes, are text boxes. I want the user to fill them in and display them on the Print page tab. I want use text boxes so i can control how they look (not hide with the columns). I don't have code written because I don't even know how to find them, but here is the code for everything else if it helps:

```
Dim bMakeItHappen As Boolean

Private Sub ComboBox3_DropButtonClick()
    'If vMakeItHappen Then
    If ComboBox3 = "Frame system" Then
        Range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Range("C1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf ComboBox3 = "Color" Then
        Range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Range("C1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Range("D1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf ComboBox3 = "Door" Then
        Range("A1:C1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Range("D1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range("A1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
    'bMakeItHappen = False
    'End If

    'This macro scrolls to the top left of your spreadsheet (cell A1)
    'ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'the row you want to scroll to
    'ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1 'the column you want to scroll to

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim ra As Range
    Dim a As String

    'Variable list:
    'titl = title of header,
    'ra = cell address of found title name,
    'aa = simplified cell address,
    'rw = splic row address
    'clm = splic column address,
    'x = counting range,
    'cnt = counted cell numbers,
    'a = imput value 1,
    'b = imput value 2,
    'c = a and b joined
    'e = defining sections above or below

    titl = Me.ComboBox3

    'these to sets find the titles locations
    Set ra = Worksheets("Print page").Cells.Find(What:=titl, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ra Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Not found")
    Else
        aa = ra.Address
    End If

    rw = Range(aa).Row
    clm = Range(aa).Column

    x = aa + ":B44"

    cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Print page").Range(x), "?*")

    'setting values for Do Until loop below
    tr = Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value

    'Reads cell values, maybe could change to a for loop to do larger quantities or set directly to drop down menu
    If titl = "Frame system" Then
        a = Cells(4, 1).Value
        b = Cells(4, 2).Value
        c = a & " " & b
    ElseIf titl = "color" Then
        c = Cells(4, 3).Value
    ElseIf titl = "Door" Then
        g = Cells(4, 4).Value
        h = Cells(4, 5).Value
        i = Cells(4, 6).Value
        j = Cells(4, 7).Value
        c = g & " " & h & " " & i & " " & j
    Else
        c = Cells(4, 1).Value
    End If

    MsgBox (c)

    If Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = tr Then
        Do Until Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = ""
            rw = rw + 1
        Loop
    End If

    Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    ' writes it to correct location
    If Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = "" Then
        Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = c
    Else: Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw + cnt, clm).Value = c
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't think this will help much, but I am trying get the information from a text box called from the large program (the second one)

Comment: To answer your question: it most probably is possible. That said, SO is not a free code writing service. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60420400/edit) to supply the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the "design mode" button on the Developer tab and examine your textboxes (right-click >> Properties) to find their names.

Once you have the names it would look something like this:

```
Dim tb
Set tb = Me.OLEObjects("Textbox1").Object
Me.Range("A1").Value = tb.Text
```

Comment: I was trying to use text boxes from the insert tab, that is why I couldn't find a name. Thanks for the clarification/Answer.